# Is it possible to add a link to an exe in Visual Studio project using add existing item?

Tags: visual-studio

I tried and it doesn't work. Did I mischief something or is it impossible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

- Choose Add -> Existing Item...
- You will probably need to change the file filter in the file browser to "All files (*.*)" to make the .exe files show.
- Single click the exe file you want to add a link to.
- Click the down arrow next to the add button and choose "Add As Link".

The exe should now appear in your project as a linked item.

It is an odd thing to do though, so I question the merit in doing it.

Comment: That's what I did but nothing appears.

Comment: If the exe you are linking to is under your project directory, it does look like it adds it directly instead of as a link.